# How to change Primary Language of already approved app in new version?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

**In App Information** -> **Primary Language** option is not actionable. But when I view at top right 2 Languages is coming, marked english as primary. And also if I check Prepare for submission both language are coming there as well.

[image: Attached screenshot of iTunes]

Answer (score 3):

You have to replacing your app with a New Version.

[See this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html)

See this image

[image]

Comment: I checked this link: there is no information showing for app to change language in new version. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH28-SW1

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, you can't directly change the primary language. You first have to get your app approved with the desired language set as an additional language.

This is from [Apple's documentation](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve6f78a8e2?sub=devb34f436a9):

> You can change the primary language for an app. In order for a language to be selectable as a primary language:
>
> - You must already have added the language to a previous version.
> - The new language must be approved by App Review. If the language has not been approved, submit a version with this localized metadata to be approved. Then, select it as your primary language on a subsequent update.
> - You must already have uploaded screenshots for that language that were approved by App Review. If the screenshots for that localization are being derived from another localization’s screenshots, you must first manually add screenshots for that language and submit a version with these screenshots to be approved. Then, select it as your primary language on a subsequent update.
>
> 1.From the homepage, click My Apps, then select the app.
>
> 2.From the Primary Language pop-up menu, choose the new primary language.

[image]